# Django mail failed to send mail to icloud mail id

Tags: django, icloud, django-mailer

I used the below code

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
email = EmailMessage('Hello', 'World', to=['user@gmail.com'])
email.send()
```

the message is sent when I used any other mail except icloud, the code says the message has been sent but I didn't receive any message.
Is this Django issue or some policies of icloud is blocking it?

Comment: Did you try sending to other email emails?

Answer (score 0):

If it works with other mails, than it's most likely an ICloud thing.
Gmail for example considers the SMPT Api as less secure than their G-Mail Api. In order be able to use it you need to grant access for less secure apps maybe there's a similar thing in ICloud.

Stupid question: Have you looked in your spam folder?